# Index sql error

Tags: magento2, sql, reindex

When I run indexer:reindex I get the following SQL error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'condition IS NOT NULL)' at line 5, query was: 

UPDATE `catalog_product_flat_1_tmp_indexer` AS `et`
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `t0` ON t0.option_id = et.condition AND t0.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `ts` ON ts.option_id = et.condition AND ts.store_id = 1
SET `et`.`condition_value` = IFNULL(ts.value, t0.value)
WHERE (condition IS NOT NULL)
```

I can't work out what attributes are cuasing it, this happened updating between 2.2.7 -> 2.2.8

Answer (score 0):

You should not use condition as a variable as it is declared in mysql :
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare-condition.html

However, now that you have used, you should always add escape with **`** like you can see for other places. The last **where clause** seems to be a custom from your module which you need to modify. So, after modification it should look like this:

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_flat_1_tmp_indexer` AS `et`
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `t0` ON t0.option_id = et.condition AND t0.store_id = 0
 LEFT JOIN `eav_attribute_option_value` AS `ts` ON ts.option_id = et.condition AND ts.store_id = 1
SET `et`.`condition_value` = IFNULL(ts.value, t0.value)
WHERE (`condition` IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm not writing a custom module. This just happens when I run ```php bin/magento indexer:reindex```

Comment: I got that. Actually what I am trying to highlight is in one of the custom modules you might have done something like this:

$this->dbCollectionModel->getSelect()->where('condition IS NOT NULL'); 

and if it is then you should change it to something like this:

$this->dbCollectionModel->getSelect()->where('`**`condition`**` IS NOT NULL');

Unable to add ` character for _condition_

Comment: I'll search the codebase for that but I have disabled all custom modules I'm using and I still get the error.